# If a liquid is compressed enough, would it become solid?

Tags: condensed-matter

If a liquid were to be compressed so tensely that the particles had no room to move, would it then become a solid?
Also, would the same happen with a gas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the substance. It is easy to work out though from the relevant [phase diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram).

Isothermally increasing the pressure of liquid CO$_2$ will create a solid phase (dry ice). But increasing the pressure of liquid water will not create ice.

A gas-to-solid transition with increasing pressure is a process called [deposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposition_%28phase_transition%29). It will happen with most substances if the temperature is sufficiently low.

Comment: I disagree that increasing the pressure of liquid water at a fixed temperature will not create ice. Take a look at the phase diagram [on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice#Phases). At 300 K, you can increase pressure to get Ices 6, 7, 10 and 11.

Comment: @tpg2114: interesting ! might we find ice in the lower levels of the earth crust ? temperature from 200°C to 400°, pressure probably higher than 1 GPa ...

Comment: @igael It's possible. There is actually a planet theorized to have a surface of very hot ice, [Gliese 436b](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_436_b). That **awesomeness** has been scaled back slightly, but it is still thought to have sub-surface hot ice due to the intense pressure/gravity.

Comment: @lemon: then just change water to helium.